# Difference between closures in python and javascript

Tags: javascript, python, closures

In JS, we can write closure like:

```
function f(){
var a=0;
function g(){
    alert(a++);
}
return g;
}
g=f()
g()
```

However, if I write following code in python

```
def f():
    a=0
    def g():
        a+=1
        print a
    return g
g=f()
g()
```

Then I get *UnboundedLocalError*.

Can anyone tell me the difference between closure in python and JS?

Comment: Do you really believe that this difference will explain what you're seeing?

Comment: I think so. Direct explanation of the observed result is also welcome

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use `a += 1` in Python it refers to a local (uninitialized) variable in scope of `g` function.  Basically you can read variables from upper scopes, but if you try to write it will refer to a variable in most recent scope.  To make it work like you want you have to use `nonlocal` keyword that is only present Python 3.  In Python 2 you can't do that as far as I know, unless the variable you're trying to change is is global, then `global` keyword comes to the rescue.

```
def f():
    a=0
    def g():
        nonlocal a
        a+=1
        print a
    return g
g=f()
g()
```

Comment: In Python 2, `a = [0]` and `a[0] += 1` makes it work. This works because item assignment (along with member and slice assignment) doesn't count as overwriting a variable, you instead change state of an object (under the hood, you call a method).

Comment: Looks like an ugly hack but it is indeed a way out.

Comment: This is related to the fact that integers are immutable: `a += 1` is the same as `a = a + 1` for `int`s. It binds the name `a` to a new expression instead of modifying the object currently named by `a`, like a list operation does.

Comment: It `is` an ugly hack, That's why Python3 adds nonlocal afterall. Usually it is better to design the code to not need this kind of hack, but sometimes the complication of the alternative could be works than using the hacky way

Answer (score 2):

Version for python 2:

```
def f():
    a=0
    def g():
        g.a+=1
        print g.a

    g.a=a
    return g
g=f()
g()
```

Comment: this is different from expected: calling g() twice return the same result

Comment: @user607722 fixed the problem code. Tested repeated calls. It might be better coded as a generator though to simplify keeping state.